# UITableViewCells with UICollectionView inside Low performance (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a tableview with nested in each cell a collectionView.

The number of tableViewCell is dynamic and also the number of collectionViewCell for each tableViewCell is dynamic.

I "dequeueReusableCell" both kind of cells.

Every time that I load a tableViewCell I do cell.collectionView.reloadData().

TableView is really jerking when I scroll it. Plus the viewController takes a lot to load.

I tried to move collectionView.reloadData() in prepareforReuse of uitableviewcell, or in willDisplayCell, but nothing.

I found few posts asking this question, but actually I could not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using `reloadData()` method is like using an hammer. It costs a lot because you are saying to reload all your data.

The question to ask yourself is : "Do I need to reload all the data every time ? Or only a part of that ? Just a row with `func reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` ? Just a section maybe with `func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` ?

With those methods you can reduce the cost and speed up a little your program.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, but not in my case. My problem is that each tableview row can be different, and reusing the cells, every time that I scroll down, I need to reload the whole row, which means reload the collectionview inside the tableviewcell. CollectionViews can be all different, but they contains few cells each, not more. Think about the new Apple store app. Each row contains a different collection view. Is it better to have many tableViews of one row, so actually rows are not reused?